# Possible unhandled promise rejection warning with useMutation

Tags: react-apollo, react-apollo-hooks

I'm getting an unhandled promise rejection error when I use `useMutation` with react native. Here's the code producing the issue:

```
const [createUser, { error, loading }] = useMutation(CREATE_USER_MUTATION);
```

Anytime my graphql server returns an error to the client I get an unhandled promise rejection error (screenshot below). I'm able to make it go away by adding an error handler like so, but it seems like a hack. Any thoughts? Am I doing something wrong or is this something that should be addressed by the apollo folks?

```
const [createUser, { error, loading }] = useMutation(CREATE_USER_MUTATION, {
  onError: () => {}
});
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like this answer has a detail explanation of what's going on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59472340/23427.

Answer (score 2):

Your `createUser` mutation is a promise you should handle error inside `try catch` block, or in upper scope inside [apollo-link-error](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/link/links/error/) `onError` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
const [createUser, { data, loading }] = useMutation(CREATE_USER_MUTATION, {
  onError: (err) => {
      setError(err);
  }
});
```

With this we can access data with loading and proper error handling.