# Handling errors with react-apollo useMutation hook

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

I have been trying to get my head around this problem but haven't found a strong answer to it. I am trying to execute a login mutation using the `useMutation` hook.

***TLDR; I want to know what exactly is the difference between the `onError` passed in `options` and `error` given to me by the `useMutation`***

Here's my code snippet

```
const [login, { data, loading, error }] = useMutation(LOGIN_QUERY, {
  variables: {
    email,
    password
  },
  onError(err) {
    console.log(err);
  },
});
```

On the server-side, I have a preset/hardcoded email used for login and I am not using Apollo or any other client. In the resolver of this Login Mutation, I simply throw an error if the email is not same using

```
throw new Error('Invalid Email');
```

Now I want to handle this error on the client-side (React). But my concern is that if I use the 'error' returned from the `useMutation` hook and try to show the error in this way

```
render() {
  ...
  {error && <div> Error occurred </div>}
  ...
}
```

the error is updated in the UI but then immediately React shows me a screen with:

```
Unhandled Rejection (Error): Graphql error: My-custom-error-message
```

But, if I use `onError` passed in `options` to `useMutate` function, then it doesn't show me this screen and I can do whatever I want with the error.

I want to know what exactly is the difference between the `onError` passed in `options` and `error` given to me by the `useMutation` and why does React show me that error screen when `onError` is **not** used.

Thanks!

Answer (score 296, accepted):

Apollo exposes two kinds of errors through its API: **GraphQL errors**, which are returned as part of the response as `errors`, alongside `data`, and **network errors** which occur when a request fails. A network error will occur when a server can't be reached or if the response status is anything other than 200 -- queries that have `errors` in the response can still have a status of 200. But an invalid query, for example, will result in a 400 status and a network error in Apollo Client.

Apollo Client actually provides four different ways to handle mutation errors:

1.) Calling the `mutate` function returned by the hook returns a Promise. If the request is successful, the Promise will *resolve* to a response object that includes the `data` returned by the server. If the request fails, the Promise will *reject* with the error. This is why you see an "Unhandled Rejection" message in the console -- you need to handle the rejected Promise.

```
login()
  .then(({ data }) => {
    // you can do something with the response here
  })
  .catch(e => {
    // you can do something with the error here
  })
```

or with async/await syntax:

```
try {
  const { data } = await login()
} catch (e) {
  // do something with the error here
}
```

By default, the Promise will reject on **either** GraphQL errors or network errors. By setting the [errorPolicy](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/error-handling/#graphql-error-policies) to `ignore` or `all`, though, the Promise will **only** reject on network errors. In this case, the GraphQL errors will still be accessible through the response object, but the Promise will resolve.

2.) The only exception to the above occurs when you provide an `onError` function. In this case, the Promise will always resolve instead of rejecting, but if an error occurs, `onError` will be called with the resulting error. The `errorPolicy` you set applies here too -- `onError` will always be called for network errors but will only be called with GraphQL errors when using the default `errorPolicy` of `none`. Using `onError` is equivalent to catching the rejected Promise -- it just moves the error handler from the call site of the `mutate` function to the call site of the hook.

3.) In addition to the `mutate` function, the `useMutation` hook also returns a result object. This object also exposes any errors encountered when running the mutation. Unlike the error handler functions we wrote above, this `error` object represents *application state*. Both the `error` and `data` objects exposed this way exist as a convenience. They are *equivalent* to doing this:

```
const [mutate] = useMutation(YOUR_MUTATION)
const [data, setData] = useState()
const [error, setError] = useState()
const handleClick = async () => {
  try {
    const { data } = await mutate()
    setData(data)
  catch (e) {
    setError(e)
  }
}
```

Having error state like this can be useful when you want your UI to reflect the fact there's an error. For example, you might change the color of an element until the mutation runs without an error. Instead of having to write the above boilerplate yourself, you can just use the provided result object.

```
const [mutate, { data, error }] = useMutation(YOUR_MUTATION)
```

**NOTE:** While you can use the exposed error state to update your UI, doing so is *not* a substitute for actually *handling* the error. You *must* either provide an `onError` callback or `catch` the error in order to avoid warnings about an unhandled Promise rejection.

4.) Lastly, you can also use [apollo-link-error](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/link/apollo-link-error/) to add *global* error handling for your requests. This allows you to, for example, display an error dialog regardless of where in your application the request originated.

Which of these methods you utilize in your application depends heavily on what you're trying to do (global vs local, state vs callback, etc.). Most applications will make use of more than one method of error handling.

Comment: This is really great, if I want to use the convenient `data` and `error` from `useMutation`, what do I do with the `data` and `error` when handling the Promise? Since I don't have to set them myself.

Answer (score 10):

```
const [mutationHandler, { data, loading }] = useMutation(YOUR_MUTATION, {
  onError: (err) => {
      setError(err);
  }
});
```

With this we can access data with loading status and proper error handling to avoid any error in console / unhandled promise rejection.

Comment: one note, looks like we would need to expose the `reset()` method hook, such that we can call in `onError` callback, so that the `loading` state gets reset correctly.

Answer (score 1):

```
const YOUR_COMPONENT = ({ setError }) => {
  // ... 

   const [mutationHandler, { data, loading }] = useMutation(YOUR_MUTATION, {                                             
          onError: (error) => {
          setError(error.graphQLErrors[0].message)
   }
})
```

This will handle the errors