# Apollo error handling - why react app crashes?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

is somebody able to explain, why my react app + apollo behaves like this when I try to use mutation which returns error?

[image]

GraphQL mutation returns this (response code is 200): `{"errors":[{"error":{"result":"identity.not-found","error":"authentication-failed","statusCode":401}}],"data":{"login":null}}`

My mutation looks like this:

```
export const LOGIN_MUTATION = gql`
    mutation($input: LoginInput!) {
        login(input: $input) {
            token
        }
    }
`;
```

called:

```
const handleSignIn = () => {
        loginMutation({
            variables: {
                input: {
                    clientId: config.clientId,
                    username: userName,
                    password: password,
                    clientSecret: config.clientSecret
                }
            }
        });
    };
```

It behaves for awhile like expected (my own custom error component is rendered - `{error && <div>error</div>}`), but then it throws this unhandled rejection.

If I add catch callback to mutation call, it works as expected.

However, I did not find anywhere in apollo docs any mentions about the need to always catch GraphQL errors such way. This should be sufficient, if I understand it correctly: const `[loginMutation, {data, loading, error}] = useMutation(LOGIN_MUTATION);`

Is this behaviour correct or do I miss something?

Versions:

```
"@apollo/react-hooks": "^3.1.3"
"apollo-boost": "^0.4.7"
"graphql": "^14.5.8"
```

Answer (score 4):

The `mutate` function returns a Promise that, by default, will be rejected if your response includes an `errors` object or if a network error occurs. If you change the `errorPolicy` to `ignore` or `all`, the presence of `errors` in your response won't cause the Promise to reject, but a network error still will.

The only way to avoid this behavior is to provide an error handler through the `onError` parameter. If `onError` is provided, the Promise returned by `mutate` will always resolve and any relevant errors (depending on your `errorPolicy`) will be passed to `onError` instead.

Additional details on error handling in Apollo can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59465864/handling-errors-with-react-apollo-usemutation-hook/59472340#59472340). Additional details on unhandled Promise rejections can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40500490/what-is-an-unhandled-promise-rejection).

Comment: If I understand this correctly, modifying hook like this: `const [loginMutation, {data, loading, error}] = useMutation(LOGIN_MUTATION, {errorPolicy: 'all'});` should solve my issue and error screen should not appear. But it does. Only way to prevent that is using catch

Comment: Yes to be honest, Apollo (or apollo-boost, idk if the behavior changed) is pretty annoying.The same happens to me, on ignore "all" the error is returned but the promise is its rejected. It is trickier, because the docs are confusing and the answers do not seem to say the same thing I´ve been experiencing.