# useMutation error resolves into Unhandled Rejection (Error) page

Tags: reactjs, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

How can I handle errors for `useMutation` so the page doesn't turn into an unpleasant `Unhandled Rejection (Error)`?

While this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59465864/handling-errors-with-react-apollo-usemutation-hook) describes my problem, I still couldn't solve it. The post especially mentions. `Instead of having to write the above boilerplate yourself, you can just use the provided result object.` I did that with:

`const [signUp, { loading: mutationLoading, error: mutationError } [...]`

However, my React App always switches to a not nice "Unhandled Rejection (Error): GraphQL error" screen when an error occurs. A similar solution seems to work in the [official doc](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/) – but not for me.

```
function SignUp() {
  // Declare a new state variable, which we'll call "count"
  const [login, setLogin] = useState(true);
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [
    signUp,
    { loading: mutationLoading, error: mutationError }
  ] = useMutation(SIGNUP_MUTATION, {
    onCompleted(data) {
      const { token } = login ? data.tokenAuth : data.createUser;
      localStorage.setItem(AUTH_TOKEN, token);
      console.log(token);
      // this.props.history.push(`/`);
    }
  });

  return (
    <div>
      {mutationLoading && <p>Loading...</p>}
      {mutationError && (
        <p>
          Some error occured :(
          {console.log(mutationError)}
          {mutationError.graphQLErrors.map(({ message }, i) => (
            <span key={i}>{message}</span>
          ))}
        </p>
      )}
[...]
```

Comment: I wrote: "**Having error state like this can be useful when you want your UI to reflect the fact there's an error**. For example, you might change the color of an element until the mutation runs without an error. Instead of having to write the above boilerplate yourself, you can just use the provided result object."

Comment: The `error` object is exposed as a convenience for manipulating your UI. It's not a substitute for actually handling the error using 1) `catch` or 2) `onError` or 3) using ErrorLink and removing the errors from the response.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Daniel. You you give me an example for my code with 1) I couldn't manage to create a working version with that example

Comment: `signUp.catch(e => /* do something with the error */)`

Answer (score 0):

```
const [
    signUp,
    { loading: mutationLoading}
  ] = useMutation(SIGNUP_MUTATION, {
    onCompleted(data) {
      const { token } = login ? data.tokenAuth : data.createUser;
      localStorage.setItem(AUTH_TOKEN, token);
      console.log(token);
      // this.props.history.push(`/`);
    },
   onError: (err) => {
      setError(err);
    // mutationError = err;
   }
  });
```