# How to Fix Bug in Apollo-link for GraphQL Error

Tags: error-handling, apollo, apollo-client, apollo-link

In here, I can both graphQLErrors and networkError:

```
  const errorLink = onError(({ operation, graphQLErrors, networkError, forward }) => {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
      if (networkError) {
        console.log(`[Network Error]:`, networkError.message);
      }
      if (graphQLErrors) {
        graphQLErrors.forEach((error) => {
          console.log(`[GraphQL Error]:`, error.message);
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

but when trying to get these errors inside useQuery, at the component level, only networkError is returned while graphQLErrors is an empty array:

```
let { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_ALL_PROJECTS, {
 variables: { pageNum: 1, pageSize: 10 },
 fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
 });
```

For example, I get an error 403 to onError function from backend, but could not handle this error inside useQuery!

[image]
How to fix this issue??

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here. Either there was a `networkError` or else the request was successful but there were `graphQLErrors`. A request would never return both.

Comment: Correct, I log both errors in the profile page, but graphQLErrors is empty and networkError throw Instead of graphQLError.

Comment: That's the expected behavior. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59465864/handling-errors-with-react-apollo-usemutation-hook/59472340#59472340). What exactly is your question?

Comment: This problem is open on the GitHub issues. Please see https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-link/issues/1285

Answer (score 0):

Apollo client passes either `graphQLErrors` or `networkError` forward, that's true. I believe it's under an assumption that when the network error happens, the GraphQL error in returned data is more technical and shouldn't be shown to the user. If you really want to access the additional error info sent by your server, you can actually access it in `networkError.result.errors`.

My code in typescript extracting the error:

```js
const { networkError } = error
const networkGraphQLErrorsPresent =
  networkError &&
  "result" in networkError &&
  networkError.result.errors &&
  networkError.result.errors.length > 0
const extractedError =
  networkGraphQLErrorsPresent ?
    (networkError.result.errors[0] as GraphQLError) :
    undefined
```