# onCompleted of useMutation get executed even on error

Tags: reactjs, react-apollo, apollo-client

When I'm using the useMutation hook and getting an error on the response the onCompleted method gets triggered.  Is that normal behavior?

```
 const [createPerson] = useMutation(CreatePerson, {
   onCompleted: () => {
     console.log('even onError it`s executed')
   }
 })
```

Comment: Can you please also post the `createPerson` call? It is not normal behavior. Normal behavior would be to fire something like `onError`.

Comment: This is the response I'm getting from the server: {data: null, errors: [{message: ''already exist", path: ["/createPerson"], ....}],... }

Comment: Yeah, I am more interested in the full function call, as there could be a problem in the error handling.

Comment: await createPerson({
        variables: { input: { name: user.name, email: user.email } },
      })

Comment: Did you set a specific error policy?

Comment: yes, on ApolloProvider. Do you think it's related?
I did it  because I want to handle the errors myself and to not have the apollo error page for default

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222899/discussion-between-gh05d-and-arie5).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From our discussion in the chat I take that you have set the error policy of the `Apollo Provider` to `ignore`:

> ignore: Ignore allows you to read any data that is returned alongside GraphQL Errors, but doesn't save the errors or report them to your UI.

This is the reason that the *GraphQL* errors are ignored. They will only be triggered when using the default policy of `none`.

More info about the error policies [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/error-handling/) and in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59465864/handling-errors-with-react-apollo-usemutation-hook).

Comment: I will change it to the default error policy, 
now I trying to catch all the API errors in the apolloProider because I want to prevent the default error page

Comment: If you want to keep your current structure, you could also check the status code on the data prop that you get from the `onCompleted` function and only do stuff when there is no error. But this is kind of a hack and would have to be implemented everywhere.